# template class specification and inhertiance

Tags: c++, class, templates, inheritance, template-specialization

```
template<typename T>
class CommonBase
{
};

template<typename T>
class Base : public CommonBase<T>
{
 protected:
  bool flag;
};

template<>
class Base<int> : public CommonBase<int>
{
  Base() {flag = false;}
};
```

It causes an error that "`flag` is not declared in the namespace". Where did I do wrong?

Comment: When T is an int, the compiler selects the specialization, which is the entire implementation of Base that is used.  For all other types, it uses the primary template.  They don't merge, it is one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

It is an explicit specialization of the class template `Base`.

You have to include the data member flag in the class definition

```
template<>
class Base<int> : public CommonBase<int>
{
protected:
  bool flag;
public:
  Base() {flag = false;}
};
```

From the C++ 20 Standard (13.8.3 Explicit specialization)

> 6. A **member of an explicitly specialized class is not implicitly instantiated 
>      from the member declaration of the class template; instead, the member
>      of the class template specialization shall itself be explicitly
>      defined if its definition is required**. ... The definition of an
>      explicitly specialized class is unrelated to the
>      definition of a generated specialization. That is, its members
>      need not have the same names, types, etc. as the members of a
>      generated specialization. Members of an explicitly specialized class
>      template are defined in the same manner as members of normal classes,
>      and not using the template<> syntax....

Comment: Do I need to include all the membters in `class Base : public CommonBase<T> ` into  `class Base<int> : public CommonBase<int>` ?

Comment: @IgorG look closer :)

Comment: @SteveYang You have to define the specialization of the class Base<int>.

Answer (score 1):

An explicit specialisation of class template *wholly replaces* the primary template for that particular set of template arguments. In your case, this means that `Base<int>` is in no way related to what would be generated from `Base<T>` without the specialisation existing. The explicit specialisation definition is the *complete* definition of the class for the specialisation's template arguments.

If you want to use some parts of the primary template and override other ones, you have to extract the parts to be retained into a non-specialised base class. Perhas like this:

```
template<typename T>
class CommonBase
{
};

template<typename T>
class Base_Reusable : public CommonBase<T>
{
 protected:
  bool flag;
};

template <class T>
class Base : public Base_Reusable<T>
{
};

template<>
class Base<int> : public Base_Reusable<int>
{
  Base() {flag = false;}
};
```